# How can I generate a string similar to YouTube's video identifier string in Java?

Tags: java, identifier

### Edits: I reworded this question.

I notice that at YouTube, each video has a unique string such as 1cru2fzUlEc to identify itself.

I am wondering how I can do the same thing efficiently in Java.

Thanks for any input.

Cheers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a unique ID in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389736/how-do-i-create-a-unique-id-in-java)

Comment: The reworded question is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-java

Comment: om-nom-nom and Patashu, thanks for the links, which is quite helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Patashu already pointed out: These strings are not encrypted they are simply unique identifiers which cannot be guessed or calculated.

This can be achieved in Java using the [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29) [implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29). These UUIDs are longer than youtube's but the principle is the same.

The security of these UUIDs should be good enough for almost all occasions, as has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513573/how-good-is-javas-uuid-randomuuid).

Answer (score 3):

with apache commons-lang

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;

public static final int ID_LENGTH = 11;

public String generateUniqueId() {
    return RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(ID_LENGTH);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sites such as youtube don't 'encrypt' the identifier of a video. When the video is made it generates a random string for it, and that random string (after making sure it is unique) IS the video's identifier.

Comment: Thank you, Patashu. You are right. I mixed up two things together. I re-worded my question