# How to insert database from java a random unique integer?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i want to create a priority number where an account will  e  randomly given a unique number. I'm still currently learning java and mysql pardon any mistakes and i hope you'll help me solve this. thanks!

```
    public void add() {
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  // MySQL database connection
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/system?" + "user=root&password=");
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into customer values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        //customer_id
        pstmt.setInt(1, 0);
        //customer_name
        pstmt.setString(2, tf_name.getText());
        //customer_address
        pstmt.setString(3, tf_address.getText());
        //customer_contactqw
        pstmt.setString(4, tf_contact.getText());
        //customer_email
        pstmt.setString(5, tf_email.getText());
        //order_priority
        pstmt.setInt(6, 1000 + RAND() * 89999); // <-- pls help me here
        //customer_date            
        pstmt.setDate(7, convertUtilDateToSqlDate(dateChooser.getDate()));

        //execute the query
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

        //      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully added a new record!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }

}
```

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem.  In what way does this code not work as expected?  How is it failing?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you don't want to tell us what the error is?  Try to understand that we can't see your screen from here.

Comment: @David `pstmt.setInt(6, 1000 + RAND() * 89999);` i got an error here.

Comment: Then clearly you should correct that error.  Whatever that error may happen to be.  Which, again, for some reason you're refusing to show us.

Comment: Why not just do it in the database? `FLOOR(RAND() * 2147483648)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How do I create a unique ID in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389736/how-do-i-create-a-unique-id-in-java)

You can create a UUID:

```
 pstmt.setInt(6, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

Edit: There is no simple way to create an integer unique ID with no collision as there are only 2^32  options, which might end up with a collision.
You can create an array which will hold for you all the random generated numbers so far.

If you want to take the risk of collision, you can try:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
pstmt.setInt(6, random.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

If you want to track all the id's you entered so far to prevent a collision you can store them in an array.
Let's say you have `ArrayList<int> arr;`

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
boolean inserted;
do{
    inserted = true;
    int id = random.nextInt(MAX_VALUE);
    for (int i=0; i<arr.size();i++){
        if (arr.get(i) == id)
            inserted = false;
    }
    if (!inserted){
        arr.add(id);
        pstmt.setInt(6,id);
    }
}while(!inserted);
```

Comment: i received an error saying that UUID can't be converted to int.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `Math.random()` (or similar method) inside you `RAND()` method, it always returns a `double`. setInt method of PreparedStatement expects an `int` argument whereas the multiplication results in a `double` that's why the error.

You can change `setInt(..` to `setDouble(..` and it would work fine.

Comment: changed it to double but got an error that it can't find the RAND() method

Comment: try `1000 + Math.random() * 89999`. It won't 100% guarantee you the uniqueness though.