# About generating unique random numbers

Tags: java

```
  public String generateCustomerID(String id, int digit)//Customer Class

   randomGenerator = new Random();

   String index = "";

   for(int i = 1; i <= digit; i++)
   {  

       index +=  randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

   }
      return id + index;

   public void storeCustomer(Customer customer)//Shop Class
   {
    customerList.add(customer);
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    String number =   customer.generateCustomerID("AB", 1);

    set.add(number);
    customer.setCustomerID(number);

   }
```

How can i make sure that only customers with unique id are stored. For example, if customer A got id "AB-1", then customer B should have a different id like "AB-8". I tried to use Hashset but but i am not sure this is the right method to solve this problem. I do not think i need to use UIDD.

Comment: do you have a problem with making unique ids or a problem with the collection you're using?

Comment: Are these customers ultimately getting stored in a database? At what scope do they need to be unique?

Comment: I have a problem with making unique ids.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a unique ID in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389736/how-do-i-create-a-unique-id-in-java)

Comment: You are defining your `set` within `storeCustomer` so it will be recreated everytime you call this method - move it as a field.  Also you do not seem to be checking this set to see if the number exists

Comment: Not stored in a database. Each customer should have an unique id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider this solution

```
    static Set<String> taken = new HashSet <>();
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("enter id ");
            String id = scan.nextLine();
            if (taken.contains(id)) {
                System.out.println("already taken");
                continue;
            }
            taken.add (id);
            System.out.println("another [y/n]? ");
            if (scan.nextLine().equals("n"))
                break;
        }
    }
```

the key point being that `set` is a field and it is checked using `contains`

Comment: I see. Does this code just check whether the id is already taken?

Comment: Yes, `if (taken.contains(id)) {`

Comment: I tried your code but i do not know how to store the id into the customer.

Comment: well as per your original code `customer.setCustomerID(number);` just replace `number` with my more meaningful named variable `id`

Answer (score -3):

place
    `while(set.contains(number)){
       number =   customer.generateCustomerID("AB", 1);
     }`
before
    `set.add(number);customer.setCustomerID(number);`

Comment: maybe `!contains` ?

Comment: sorry it should be `contains(number)`.but what's the problem with my answer?

Comment: see my comment below the OP's question

Comment: @James Tomy place `HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();`in your class as an instance.