# Firebase - Generate Unique Keys but not with push();

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push, unique-key

I want to have my custom unique keys in firebase database as such (User1, User2, User3, User4......Usern).

When I use `push();` it generates a long and unclear key that confuses me while sorting.

I also tried `child("User1");` but it only saves once in the database with given `User1` key. Every time when i want to override Database, it only updates User1 values.

> Are there any wiser options to have custom unique keys?

Comment: This problem is also faced by me, still couldnt resolve it. I am using now push(). Anyone who can answer it??

Comment: They wrote on their blog how to do it https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) to help you generate unique keys for your Firebase database without having to use `push()`.

```
import java.util.UUID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference("User1");
    // mKey = dbRef.push().getKey();
    mKey = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
}
```

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063043/1008011) to another answer addressing generating unique keys.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `push()` to generate unique keys for your users, use the `user` object's `uid` to have user nodes in your database. You can get the `uid` of the current logged in user by calling the following line :-

```
uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

And then calling the next line to use it as a node in your database :-

```
mDatabase.child("users").child(uid).child("username").setValue("ABC");
```

This works great because :-

1. `uid` is unique for each user and is the easiest and most robust way to have and identify user nodes in the database - specially at multiple locations.
2. `uid` of logged in user can be easily obtained from the client Android app using the above line. Therefore, you won't need to specifically save and tally the unique ids on the client. This is recommended not only for simplicity, but also for security.

So, `uid` nodes are ideal for user nodes in your database. But, for all other purposes, `push()` is still the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

there isn't .. but u can create your own custom key. just like u wanted. but u have to do little more extra work. u have to read the database first.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       HashMap<String, Object> user = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                       totalUser= user.size();

                    }
          }
```

now u can add new value with ur custom key

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("user"+totalUsr).setValue(YourValue);
```

so that the structure will look like this

- yourProject
      -Users
         -user1
         -user2

and so on ....