# Create a simple bank with accounts in Java

Tags: java, account, bank

I have two interfaces Bank and Account which have some functions:

```
public interface Bank {
    String createAccount(String owner) throws IOException;
    boolean closeAccount(String number) throws IOException;
    Set<String> getAccountNumbers() throws IOException;
    Account getAccount(String number) throws IOException;
    void transfer(Account a, Account b, double amount) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException, OverdrawException, InactiveException;
}
public interface Account {
    String getNumber() throws IOException;
    String getOwner() throws IOException;
    boolean isActive() throws IOException;
    void deposit(double amount) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException, InactiveException;
    void withdraw(double amount) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException, OverdrawException, InactiveException;
    double getBalance() throws IOException;
}
```

I have a class Driver which has two inner classes Bank and Account which implements the interfaces above, the Bank has a HashMap as accounts of customers and a customer can have multiple accounts with different account numbers. The problem that i couldn't solve it, is the generating of these account numbers even multiple for each customer!!! :

```
    public class Driver {
        private Bank bank = null;
        static class Bank implements Bank {
            private final Map<String, Account> accounts = new HashMap<>();
            @Override
            public Set<String> getAccountNumbers() {
                return accounts.keySet();
            }
            @Override
            public String createAccount(String owner) {
                //TODO create new Account and return the account number
            }

            @Override
            public boolean closeAccount(String number) {
                //TODO if the account isActive and balance is zero then set it as inactive and return true.
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public bank.Account getAccount(String number) {
                return accounts.get(number);
            }

            @Override
            public void transfer(bank.Account from, bank.Account to, double amount)
                    throws IOException, InactiveException, OverdrawException {
                if (amount <= from.getBalance()) {
                    from.withdraw(amount);
                    to.deposit(amount);
                }
        }

        static class Account implements Account {
            private String number;
            private String owner;
            private double balance;
            private boolean active = true;

            Account(String owner) {
                this.owner = owner;
                //TODO set the account number ??? 
            }

            @Override
            public double getBalance() {
                return balance;
            }

            @Override
            public String getOwner() {
                return owner;
            }

            @Override
            public String getNumber() {
                return number;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isActive() {
                return active;
            }

            @Override
            public void deposit(double amount) throws InactiveException {
                if (!isActive())
                    throw new InactiveException();
                if (amount < 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                balance += amount;
            }

            @Override
            public void withdraw(double amount) throws InactiveException, OverdrawException {
                if (!isActive())
                    throw new InactiveException();
                if (amount > balance)
                    throw new OverdrawException();
                if (amount < 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                balance -= amount;
            }
        }
}
```

How to generate account numbers?
There is a HashMap with all existing Accounts into the Bank. A customer can have multiple accounts with different account numbers! How does it work like this!?

Comment: Where do you persist the data, do you use some database?

Comment: Hint: use a `static int` and increment it ....

Comment: No, i don't use any database! the accounts will be create while the code running!

Comment: does it works with static int for different customers?

Comment: He means you should use **one** counter (`static` can ensure this), to draw unique IDs from. The first account thus gets ID 1, the next gets ID 2 and so on. The bank could have this counter and provide IDs for new accounts. An account is then associated with the number and the numbers is incremented afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Bank` class could provide this feature by internally having a **counter**. It will work as all accounts are only maintained by this one bank object, and not shared with others.

If a user requests an account the bank will give it the number the counter currently displays and then increment the counter. The next request will thus get a different number.

Could look like

```
public class Bank {
    private int nextAccountId = 1;

    public int createAccount(String owner) {
        // Get account ID
        int accountId = getUniqueAccountId();

        // Create account
        ...

        return accountID;
    }

    private int getUniqueAccountId() {
        int accountId = nextAccountId;
        // Increment ID for next request
        nextAccountId++;

        return accountId;

        // Method can be made compact by just using
        // return nextAccountId++;
    }
}
```

Obviously this has some drawbacks. It is limited to the range of `int` (about 4 Mrd accounts, can of course be extended by using `long`). Users can also see how many accounts the bank already has. And it is easy to guess a valid ID of another users account.

For a more *random* approach you could use

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389736/how-do-i-create-a-unique-id-in-java) for more information.